# How to merge two mobileprovision files

Tags: ios, signing, mobileprovision

I've two different .mobileprovision files signed with the same Developer Certificate but for two different devices (UUIDs) : one iPhone and one iPad. Till now I'm keeping also two versions of the signed apps according to the mobileprovision filed used.

I can open (and edit) the .mobileprovision using Sublime Text 2. I see the difference in the key `ProvisionedDevices` and also `UUID`.

My question is: how can I merge the two .mobileprovision files in order to sign my app so that I can have just ONE copy that I can install on both devices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the best way, it's delete both your profiles and make the new one on the apple's site with all devices you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a manual task and I am not sure why you're maintaining two provisioning profiles just to keep two devices. The best way would be to login to developer portal, add your iPad to the profile that already contains iPhone and delete the iPad profile.